# SVG drag-drop not working in firefox and safari - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg, transform

I've a `ReactJS` application where I'm trying to draw `crosshair` with the help of `svg`. Everything was working fine until unless I added `transform` property to it.

```
transform: "rotate(270deg)"
```

After adding this to my crosshair section, It has stopped working on firefox and safari. Here is what I'm getting in chrome..

[image]

But In firefox, it is not working at all.. Even thought I added transform for firefox as well..

```
webkittransform: "rotate(270deg)",moztransform: "rotate(270deg)"
```

But Still this is what I'm getting

[image]

Here is my partial code of how I'm using it...

```
<section className="image-group" style={{ overflowX: startedGKHoleEditing ? "hidden" : "auto", overflowY:"hidden", height: "244px",
            webkittransform: "rotate(270deg)",moztransform: "rotate(270deg)",transform: "rotate(270deg)",marginTop: "7.1em" }}>

    <svg id="svgGreen" className={classNames} width={imageWidth} height={244}>
          <g >
            <g webkittransform={translateXY} moztransform={translateXY} transform={translateXY} >
                <image className="fade-in" xlinkHref={activeHole.image} width={mapWidth} height={mapHeight} />
            </g>

            <g id="green" webkittransform={translateXY} moztransform={translateXY}  transform={translateXY} >
            </g>

          </g>
    </svg>

</section>
```

> Can anyone guide me what I'm doing wrong here??

Comment: moztransform and webkittransform are not attributes that have any effect on any browser.

Comment: but -moz-transform was giving error on reactJS

Comment: attributes can't start with - signs either. Attributes have not had a -moz version, only CSS styles and browsers stopped doing new -moz and -webkit CSS styles years ago because people simply made multiple identical copies of everything anyway. I.e. what you're trying to do now.

Comment: so should I use both of these in Styles?? or there is any other solution of it?

Comment: I don't thing you'll get an answer unless you provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'm trying, but my code is too much scattered that I'm unable to make a small workable example and post it here